# Accessing Arrays via an identifier variable - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to access an array based on a number. Let me explain:

```
stringBuilder.append(array1[i]);
```

but I have 4 arrays, I would like to access the array like this:

```
int i;
int aNum;

stringBuilder.append(array(aNum)[i]);
```

so the array number selected depends on the value of aNum (1 - 4) where [i] being the location of the array (0 - n)

This code however doesn't work. Any ideas? Tried looking on google but can't find the correct code I need. It does seem simple but can't find the solution. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: How does the code that specifies `array` look?

Comment: Sounds like you need a 2 diminutional array.

Comment: I did not think of that. D'oh! Makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to a [two-dimensional array](https://www.google.com/search?q=two%20dimensional%20array%20java), which is an array of arrays. Here is an example:

```
/**
   <P>{@code java TwoDArray}</P>
 **/
public class TwoDArray  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      //Setup
         int[][] intArrArr = new int[4][];
         intArrArr[0] = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
         intArrArr[1] = new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8};
         intArrArr[2] = new int[] {9, 10, 11, 12};
         intArrArr[3] = new int[] {13, 14, 15, 16};
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      //Go
         int indexOfIntInSelectedArray = 1;   //The second element...
         int indexOfArray = 2;                //...in the third array.

         stringBuilder.append(intArrArr[indexOfArray][indexOfIntInSelectedArray]);

      //Output
         System.out.println("stringBuilder.toString()=" + stringBuilder.toString());
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java TwoDArray
stringBuilder.toString()=10
```

Arrays can contain theoretically contain any number of dimensions:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=multi+dimensional+array+java
- https://www.google.com/search?q=three+dimensional+array+java
- https://www.google.com/search?q=four+dimensional+array+java

Answer (score 1):

Your array is a two dimensional array (array of arrays). You need to index using two pairs of brackets:

```
int rows = 4; 
int cols = 5;
int[][] myArray = new int[rows][cols];
int row;
int col;

stringBuilder.append(myArray[row][col]);
```